# Generating Salts Via Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Numbers Using RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, cryptography

I have read that hashing passwords properly requires using a "salt" which is at least as many characters as the intended length of final hashed password. In my case, I will need salts which are 64 characters long.

For `ASP.NET` and `VB.NET`, the recommended method of creating these salts to use a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator. I am using VB.NET, so in my case, that means using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

However, I have read so many questions and forum posts today where someone tried to implement this, and others responded saying that the way they have done it is flawed and thus, the resulting salts are not cryptographically random and risk collision.

I have come up with this code to generate salts, and my question is:

**Is this implemented in a way that generates cryptographically secure salts?**

```
<%@ Page Debug="false" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" %>

<script language="VB" runat="server">

Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim iCharLength As Integer = 64
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nonANcount As Integer = 0
    Dim buffer1 As Byte() = New Byte(iCharLength - 1) {}
    Dim sSalt As Char() = New Char(iCharLength - 1) {} 'contains the salts's characters as it's built up
    Dim sPunctuations As Char() = "!@@$%^^*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?".ToCharArray()
    Dim rng As New System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider

    rng.GetBytes(buffer1) 'get a cryptographically strong series of bytes

    For i = 0 To iCharLength - 1
        'convert each byte into its representative character
        Dim rndChr As Integer = (buffer1(i) Mod 87)
        If (rndChr < 10) Then
            sSalt(i) = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt16(48 + rndChr))
        Else
            If (rndChr < 36) Then
                sSalt(i) = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt16((65 + rndChr) - 10))
            Else
                If (rndChr < 62) Then
                    sSalt(i) = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt16((97 + rndChr) - 36))
                Else
                    sSalt(i) = sPunctuations(rndChr - 62)
                    nonANcount += 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Response.Write("<pre>" & sSalt & "</pre>")

End Sub

</script>
```

Comment: I would highly suggest not trying to implement your own secure crypto code unless you know what you're doing.   Read through this and then see the code they have published:  https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode

Comment: @womp - Thanks, I've looked at that code you mentioned, and the article and it is very well done. I've converted it to vb.net from c# and it is running smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A salt consists of bytes. These bytes can be used as input for e.g. [the PBKDF2 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx129kfs(v=vs.110).aspx) to derive a password hash. If you want to convert the salt to characters, use base 64 encoding. Please do not create your own scheme for this. 8 bytes is about the minimum size for a salt, 16 is plenty and 64 is quite over the top.